# jQuery - adding class "active" to current page on menu

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code which adds `is-current` class to an active menu item, meaning the current path matches the link.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
     if (path == '/') {
         path = '/index';
        }
    $('ul li a').each(function() {
        if (this.pathname === path) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('is-current');
            }
        });
});
```

my problem is when I have link set like that:

```
      <li class="scrollspy"><a href="clients?p=mc">Manage Clients</a></li>
      <li class="scrollspy"><a href="clients?p=nc">New Clients</a></li>
```

is-current is added to both links when visited either of them, as they both contain the `window.location.pathname` of clients.

Any good idea around it? 
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide codepen for same

Comment: Are you using php with jquery ? If yes, then instead of doing jquery code for all your pages, you can simply write a dynamic function in php and use it for your side menu only, with that you will be only stick to the side menu and not all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed from pathname to `href`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery(function($) {
        var path = window.location.href;
        if (path == '/') {
         path = '/index';
        }
        $('ul li a').each(function() {
        if (this.href === path) {
           $(this).parent().addClass('is-current');
            }
        });
     });
    });
```